# Three Level Accordion - Uncollapse 3rd Level by clicking the 1st level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I created a 3 Level Accordion. It almost works fine... But if the 3rd level is collapsed and i try to uncollapse(?) the 1st level, my 2nd level items will get invisible and my 3rd level items are still visible

Here the code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Credit</th>
        <th>Debit</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>05 May 2013</td>
        <td>Credit Account</td>
        <td class="text-success">$150.00</td>
        <td class="text-error"></td>
        <td class="text-success">$150.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo11" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> Demo1 </div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo11"> Demo11 </div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>05 May 2013</td>
        <td>Credit Account</td>
        <td class="text-success">$11.00</td>
        <td class="text-error"></td>
        <td class="text-success">$161.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo21" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo2" class="accordian-body collapse">Demo2</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo21"> Demo21 </div> </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dj7Y/3049/)

Would be nice if someone has an idea.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because your data-target="#demo1" which is pointed so when u click the target it will check the demo1 id but the second option is outside of the div so it wont close the div so u have to change the structure u have to move the 3 level inside the demo1 id.

```
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo11" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> Demo1 </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo11"> Demo11 </div> </td>
        </tr>
```

**change to**

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo11" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> Demo1 
                <div>
              <div colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo11"> Demo11 tytjtyty</div>         </div>
            </div>
            </div> </td>
        </tr>
```

for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/S39oZfRWuWf4YiKFRCRE?p=preview